# Resizing to bigger proportions as original not working

Tags: images

E.g. if I use this code inside functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'featured-extra-image', 600, 300, true );
```

and the uploaded image is only 550px width, it does not resize it to 600x300 px but only to 550x300 px.

How to force WP to resize it to my custom size, even it is bigger than original uploaded image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the image to the post

1. Select "Full Size"
2. Click "Edit Image"
3. Click the "Scale" button
4. Manually edit the dimensions
5. Save all changes
6. Check to see if "Full Size" has your new dimensions
7. Click "Use as featured image"